# Import Error after installing OpenEXR

Tags: python, opencv, openexr

I have installed OpenCV 3.0 in my system as given on this [page](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html). After successful installation, I imported cv2 from python, but it gives this error

```
ImportError: libIlmImf.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After this error, I referred one of the solutions to this error, which mentioned to install openexr. But since its already present in the 3rd party folder, so I inserted the path of OpenEXR in the python sys.path. But it still gives the same error.

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: maybe you will like this http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

Comment: That means I need to separately install opencv with python?

Comment: "sudo apt-get install python-opencv"   @AshutoshMishra